# Moq in .Net with 2 parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to create a Mock to run my tests but I am getting the following error, 
"Invalid callback. Setup on method with 2 parameter(s) cannot invoke callback with different number of parameters (1)" 
Here's my Setup function

```
  private void Setup()
    {
        this.dataFactoryMock = new Mock<CommonDataFactory>();
        var commonDataFactory = new CommonDataFactory();
        this.dataFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.Factory(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>())).Returns<DateTime>(date => commonDataFactory.Factory(date, date));
    }

public class CommonDataFactory
{
    public virtual CommonData Factory(DateTime adjustedAnalysisDate, DateTime analysisDate)
    {            
        var downloadCommonData = CommonData.DownloadCommonData(adjustedAnalysisDate, analysisDate);
        this.cache.Add(key, downloadCommonData, new CacheItemPolicy());
        return downloadCommonData;
    }
}
```

If I use only one parameter in the Factory it works fine. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The expression used in the `Returns` needs to match the number of matchers used in the setup

There were two date-time argument matchers in the setup so there needs to be two used in the returns expression.

```
this.dataFactoryMock
    .Setup(factory => factory.Factory(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
    .Returns((DateTime adjustedAnalysisDate, DateTime analysisDate) => 
        commonDataFactory.Factory(adjustedAnalysisDate, analysisDate)
    );
```